# Defining ethernet port's auto-negotiation property through linux device-tree

Tags: embedded-linux, ethernet, device-tree

Is there a way to define ethernet port's auto-negotiation property through linux's device-tree?

Answer (score 1):

I think drivers are auto-negotiating by default. Of course HW must support it (PHY must be connected through MDIO to SOC).

If your question was hot to get rid of auto-negotiation then use fixed link as shown here [device tree, change fixed link ethernet phy speed runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919853/device-tree-change-fixed-link-ethernet-phy-speed-runtime)